# Eclipse Juno with Android On AMD PC Hangs

Tags: android, eclipse, amd-processor, javaw

I am facing a issue with my development environment i just format and setup  windows 7 64 bi on my pc. I install JDK 7 64Bit (version 1.7.0_67 ) & JDK 6(version 1.6.0_27). Android SDK and Eclipse JUNO (version Version: 4.2.2).
Whenver i try to run android apps or even java application eclipse hangs and javaw use 100% of cpu.
Following are the configuration of my pc

**PC Configuration**

1. AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
2. 8 GB RAM
3. 1 TB HDD

**Eclipse config :**

```
-startup   
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar  
--launcher.library   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807  
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product  
--launcher.defaultAction openFile  
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512M  
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform  
--launcher.defaultAction openFile  
-vmargs  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5  
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard  
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m  
-Xms512m   
-Xmx1024m  
-Xverify:none
```

Can anyone please tell me whats going wrong ??
I desperately need your help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you tried by increasing the ram size from the eclipse config file?

Comment: @ProkashSarkar i already did it see the configuration  file                                      
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m